# how to put search bar in flutter between header/appbar and body?

Tags: flutter, dart

how do you put the search bar like below? i've been searching everywhere but can't find it

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvfiT.jpg)

Does anyone know how to make this kind of search bar? It would be great if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can like this

```
 Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child:
              Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 300,
          child: Stack(children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              child: Container(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 50, left: 30, right: 20),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: ListTile(),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 30,
              right: 30,
              child: Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(12.0),
                    )),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                    child: TextField()),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 20, bottom: 20),
          child: Text(
            "Hot Promo ",
          ),
        ),
      ])),
    );
```